# Python: List of integers with equal sum without repetitions

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

For integers in range (1, 13) I need to build all possible variants of three integers that sum to 13. Variants should not have repetitions. For example (1,2,10), (2,1,10), (10,1,2) and (10,2,1) are all repetitions of one variant. Thus resulting list should have only one of this tuples, does not matter which one. Variants with equal integers at different position in the resulting tuple like (1,1,11) are valid as well. For these variants repetitions would be such as (1,1,11), (1,11,1) and (11,1,1).

To give maybe a better explanation of the problem here is the story where it comes from:

Two friends Alan and Drake meet.

Alan: I have three kids.

Drake: How old are they?

Alan: The sum of the kids ages equals to 13.

So I am trying to get a list of all possible ages.

I have this code, which generates all possible repetitions that I need to drop:

```
ages = list(range(1,13))
kids_ages = []
for a in ages:
  for b in ages:
    for c in ages:
      if a + b + c == 13:
        kids_ages.append((a,b,c))
```

As a result I get:

```
([(1, 1, 11),
(1, 2, 10),
(1, 3, 9),
(1, 4, 8),
(1, 5, 7),
(1, 6, 6),
(1, 7, 5),
(1, 8, 4),
(1, 9, 3),
(1, 10, 2),
(1, 11, 1),
(2, 1, 10),
(2, 2, 9),
(2, 3, 8),
...
```

How to get rid of repetitions?

Comment: you could try parsing the current kids_ages instance with something like `int(i) for i in kids_ages.split() if i.isdigit()` then sorting and evaluating, don't know about the performances tho

Comment: I think that itertools.combinations is what you need, try to look into it...

Comment: Complexity of your algorithm is O(n^3) i think you should rewrite it with O(n) complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import itertools

res=list(sorted(el) for el in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 14), 3) if sum(el)==13)

print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[[1, 1, 11], [1, 2, 10], [1, 3, 9], [1, 4, 8], [1, 5, 7], [1, 6, 6], [2, 2, 9], [2, 3, 8], [2, 4, 7], [2, 5, 6], [3, 3, 7], [3, 4, 6], [3, 5, 5], [4, 4, 5]]

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 1):

frozenset can help you here remove duplicates.

```
ages = list(range(1,13))
kids_ages = []
for a in ages:
  for b in ages:
    for c in ages:
      if a + b + c == 13:
        kids_ages.append((a,b,c))

result=set(map(frozenset, kids_ages))
print(result)
```

Comment: frozenset does not work, resulting list has duplicates: for example (1,2,10) and (2,1,10), etc.

Comment: this is the printed result I don't see any duplicates:                         {frozenset({1, 11}), frozenset({8, 1, 4}), frozenset({9, 2}), frozenset({3, 7}), frozenset({3, 4, 6}), frozenset({2, 5, 6}), f
rozenset({4, 5}), frozenset({3, 5}), frozenset({1, 2, 10}), frozenset({1, 5, 7}), frozenset({1, 6}), frozenset({8, 2, 3}), fro
zenset({2, 4, 7}), frozenset({1, 9, 3})}

Comment: you still must be printing the kids_ages list, check "result" variable

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry, you right there is no duplicates in frozenset. Yet as a result I need variants consisting of 3 integers (not two), where variants like (1,1,11) are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by only considering the lowest age for the first position and the second lowest age for the second position. In that way, looking for duplicates is not necessary.

```
ages = list(range(1,13))
kids_ages = []
# First, pick the smallest age
for age1 in range(1,13):
    remaining_sum = 13 - age1
    # Pick the next smallest age
    for age2 in range(age1 + 1, 13):
        age3 = 13 - age1 - age2
        if age3 > age1 and age3 > age2:
            kids_ages.append( (age1, age2, age3) )

print kids_ages
# Result:
# [(1, 2, 10), (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 6)]
```

EDIT: The solution above doesn't include variants where a number is repeated, such as (1, 1, 11). To include these, simply change one place in the code to get:

```
kids_ages = []
# First, pick the smallest age
for age1 in range(1,13):
    remaining_sum = 13 - age1
    # Pick the next smallest age, whch may be the same as the first
    for age2 in range(age1, 13):
        # Only a single number can be the third age. Check if it's valid.
        age3 = 13 - age1 - age2
        if age3 >= age2:
            kids_ages.append( (age1, age2, age3) )

# Result:
# [(1, 1, 11), (1, 2, 10), (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 7), (1, 6, 6), (2, 2, 9), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 6), (3, 3, 7), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 5), (4, 4, 5)]
```

For three numbers being the same, there's no such solution that sums to 13.

Comment: This gives just a small subset of all possible variants

Comment: My answer assumes each number must not be repeated within a variant. For example, (1, 1, 11) sums to 13 but would not be allowed. If this assumption is wrong, my method doesn't work, but otherwise I don't see any missing variants.

Comment: Variants like (1,1,11) are valid. Sorry for not explaining this in particular. Adding this to my question now.

Comment: ...and I have amended my solution to solve this. :-)

Comment: Could not find in your new solution, for example (6,6,1)